# Scala compiler not executing the values which are not returned

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am new to scala. Recently I was writing some code and found some unusual behaviour with scala. So I had written this code

```
for {
  verification <- verifyReset(hash, timestamp, id)
  resp = if (verification) {
          setPassword(id, password)
          setActive(id)
          HttpResponse(Accepted, Seq(Location(Empty withPath Path / id)))
  } else HttpResponse(Unauthorized)
} yield resp
```

Here `setPassword` and `setActive` are used to do some DB operations. But while testing I found that this loop yielded resp(`Accepted`) without actually executing `setpassword` and `setActive`. 
For which I hypothesized that since the compiler doesn't actually need to execute those functions in-order to return the last statement, it didn't execute them.

But then, I wrote a similar function which behaved pretty different than my hypothesis,

```
r = if(true){
     println("1st statement")
     println("2nd statement")
     2*3
}
```

I got `r` as 6 (normal behavior), but it also gave me output on console

`1st statement
 2nd statement`

I didn't understand this because in calculating `2*3` I don't need to execute `println`, So why was `println` executed?

Comment: If you could show us your `setPassword` and `setActive` functions, it might be easier to help you.

Comment: If your hypothesis were correct, you'd never ever be able to successfully call `println` as it doesn't even have a result that can be used. Your hypothesis is not correct.

Comment: Is this behavior because of `lazy eval` going inside `for-comprehension`, which is not so in the second case?

Answer (score 4):

> Your Hypothesis is wrong here.

It will execute all operations before returning the last statement. As the the last statement is returned by default. There must be some other error with

`setPassword(id, password)
 setActive(id)`

Comment: I assure you there is no error with `setPassword` or `setActive`

Comment: @AyushAgarwal If that is the case. Please paste your code for the main method object. It would be easier to debug